# How to Share DSL(PPPoE) Connection

Tags: internet, pppoe

## How to Share DSL(PPPoE) Connection?

I'm Using Ubuntu 12.10 . I have a DSL internet connection (PPPoE). In our Local area network only one can be connected to the DSL connection at a same time. So I want to share the DSL connection from my computer so that others can connect to internet through my Computer. some also have Windows XP in our network. No Wi-fi, all are connected through wier. **PLEASE HELP**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can by making your Ubuntu 12.10 machine as a DHCP server.

To install DHCP server, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
```

For information, and how to, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/dhcp3-server) or [here](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/how-to-install-the-dhcp-server-on-ubuntu-12-04lts/)